# I would, but I have an important meeting

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

Can we use "would" in the sense of *but I/we/he won't*? For example:

Person A: Can you come with me for shopping this evening?

Person B: I **would**, but I have an important meeting to attend. (meaning *I won't*)

Comment: That is a perfectly valid answer, but **I would** means _I would be happy to come if I could_, not _I won't_.

Comment: So B's response in the OP means "they can't", and not "they won't". Am I right?

Comment: B would like to come, **but** they can't. If they really didn't want to or were being less friendly, they could have said "I can't, **because** I have an important meeting."